# mariadb new install : Checking for corrupt, not cleanly closed and upgrade needing tables

Tags: mariadb

I installed mariadb-server.

never installed before mysql.

/var/lib/mysql was empty.

```
# apt-get install mariadb-server

blah~blah~

# service mysql restart
* Stopping MariaDB database server mysqld                                                                                     [ OK ] 
* Starting MariaDB database server mysqld                                                                                     [ OK ] 
* Checking for corrupt, not cleanly closed and upgrade needing tables.
```

*** Checking for corrupt, not cleanly closed and upgrade needing tables. ***

this is problem.

I try rm -Rf /var/lib/mysql

mysql_install_db

mysql_upgrade -p

I can't remove this corrupt message.

how can I?

thank you.

Comment: Please add some information. Does the server hang at this message, or does it start up correctly otherwise? Why did you remove the database folder? Does reinstalling mariadb-server work (`sudo apt-get install --reinstall mariadb-server`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What are you panicking about? It's saying it's ***checking*** for corrupt tables.

It hasn't said it has found one.

Nothing to see here.

Comment: I didn't create any databases and tables. "# mysqlcheck -p -A --auto-repair" It is not solution. thank you.

Comment: Do you understand what the word checking means? It's just testing anything that is there. It isn't an error message.